# Square BoundingBox with OpenGL JOGL Java

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to make a project in OpenGL using JOGL.

If you see my image https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmSzI.jpg, I have 4 viewports with different projections but all Teapots are out of "scale", and I want to make something like a bounding box, a square with side 1, that contains all objects on the viewports, to make a scale out of the square.

Any tips?

Comment: Why not computing the axis aligned bounding box and using its size to scale the objects in glScalef?

Comment: Could you be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're going to use the base teapot model for programs (which you shouldn't), I don't think this is something to spend your time on. When you get into actually using your own models, you will have direct control over the scale.

I would recommend at this point learning about different drawing methods in OpenGL (e.g., `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, `GL_LINE_LOOP`). Then move on to learning about vertex arrays and maybe write an OBJ importer. I can point you in the right direction if you'd like.

[Here](http://webhome.csc.uvic.ca/~pouryash/depot/HPC_Course/OpenGLDrawingMethods.pdf) is a good place to get started on different drawing techniques.
Happy coding!